# Tourist visa from Norway

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

I am a filipino citizen, and have a permanent residence permit, do I still need a visa to travel in UK for holiday?

Comment: Where do you have a permanent residence permit? In Norway?

Comment: Are you residing in Norway as the relative of an EU, EEA, or Swiss citizen?

Comment: I have permanent residence permit in Norway. I am married to a norwegian and living here for good.

Answer (score 1):

A permanent resident permit of Norway does not entitle you to visa free access in the UK. You would need to apply for a standard visitor visa.

Source: [`https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/tourism`](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/tourism)

Comment: As long as the UK remains in the EU or continues to participate in its freedom of movement scheme, a residence card *does* exempt the holder from needing a visa if the card notes that it is the residence card of a family member of an EU/EEA citizen and the traveler is traveling with or joining the EU/EEA relative in the UK.

Comment: If they are joining their relative, then they need a visa. If they are traveling with them (not mentioned in the original post) then they _may_ need one; either way there is no harm in checking with the UK consulate. At worse, you won't be charged with illegal entry if you just show up assuming things.

Comment: That is incorrect. Article 10 cards exempt the holder from visa requirements under the freedom of movement directive; freedom of movement applies to non-EU family members who are traveling with or joining the EU relative.  See https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card, especially the part covering evidence needed if not traveling with the EU/EEA relative.

Comment: I don't think that's the case here to begin with. I think this person is just a permanent resident of Norway who would like to visit the UK as a tourist, and wondering if their permanent resident status grants them any exceptions for visa requirements to the UK.

Comment: That may or may not be true, and since we don't know whether it is true, it makes sense for the answer to mention both cases.  In other words, the correct answer to this question as asked is "maybe."

Comment: A friend of mine who reside in denmark said that when she entered in UK airport they told her that she dont need a visa she could just used the permanent residence permit...she even used it when they went to scotland... As a tourist for few days...